# python value error expected 2 recieved one when trying to put a text file into an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

im trying to get some code which will look into a text file and split the lines into 2 variable but when i run this i get the error
*ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)*
the code is:

```
x=0
f = open("scores.txt","a")    
f.write("\n")    
f.write("andrew:78")    
f.write("\n")    
f.write("karen:64")    
f.close    
f = open("scores.txt","r")        
a,b = ("karen:67").split(":")    
print (a)    
print(b)




scores = [[],[]]
while 0 != 1 :
    line=(f.readline(x))
    a,b = (line).split(":")

    scores[0] = a    
    scores[1]=b
```

thats the text file
thanks in advance

Comment: Add a `print(line)` after `line=(f.readline(x))` and check if it prints what you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to fix “ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108914/python-how-to-fix-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here     `line=(f.readline(x))` is something like this  `(["content of file"])` ie it is file content in a list which is inside a tuple .

you need to change it the size define in `x` from 0 to some value or dont use it. ie from `line = (f.readline(x))` to `line = f.readline()` it will be a string now.

now you can use split operation on string object . change `a, b = (line).split(':')` to `a, b = line.split(':')`

so new code will be

```
# opening/cretaing a file and adding data
with open("scores.txt", 'a') as f:   
    f.write("\n")    
    f.write("andrew:78")    
    f.write("\n")    
    f.write("karen:64")    


# creating a dictionary to save data of name and score respectively

scores = {'name':[], 'score':[]}

# again opening the file in read mode
with open("scores.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines() # reading all line in file at single time
    for each_line in data: 
        if line.split(':'): # checking if each line has format <name>:<score> or not, if yes then add that data to scores dict
            name, score = line.split(':')
            scores['name'].append(name)
            scores['score'].append(score)

# seeing the result
print(scores)
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that my x value is limiting how long the string will be and not what line it is taken from (I thought f.readreadline(1)  meant task all the info from line number one)

Comment: yes, kind of, no `f.readline(n)` here n define the size of the text not line, [more info](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), if you want to read all lines itself  use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()` .also dont know what you want to achive, guessing you want name and  score in `score[0]` and `score[1]` respectively so ` instead of `scores[0]=a` use `sores[0].append(a)` and similarly `scores[1].append(b)`

Comment: @drewpie just updated the code  according to your requirements and added comments so you can understand better

Comment: that looks pretty much exactly what I wanted although when you say if the line has a certain format does that part just check if there's is a colon in the middle

Answer (score 0):

It'll print out an empty character '' before the newline '\n' - I think what you want is something like:

```
lines = f.read().splitlines()
#This will only get the value for one line
scores[0], scores[1] = lines[0].split(':')

#Or to get both lines:
i=0
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    scores[i][0], scores[i][1] = line.split(':')
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code achieve what you want?

```
with open("scores.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(
        "\nandrew:78"
        "\nkaren:64"
    )

scores = []

with open("scores.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if ":" in line:
            a, b = (line).split(":")

            scores.append({a: b})
```

You were probably having an error because some lines (the blank ones) didn't have the ":" so the line was only one string which you were trying to unpack into 2 variables.